# Loader is fluctuating in IE 11

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, css-animations, microsoft-edge

I have created a simple loader using css. Is's working fine in other browsers but its fluctuating in IE 11 / Edge.

Here I have one loader div in html:

```
<div class="loader"> </div>
```

Here is my css for loader:

```
body{
  background:black;
}
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Here is fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4bukes7/)

Comment: add -ms- prefix for IE browsers .......

Comment: I have tried not working still fluctuating.

Comment: You should remove all the lines using vendor prefixes which, as you can see from your comments, haven't been needed in ages for Safari, Firefox or Opera.

Comment: Problem is that loader is spinning but its not smooth in IE as other browser. Its fluctuating in IE. @Rob

Comment: My comment is a hint to you that you are using antiquated, outdated, useless markup that no browser uses and you are pointlessly inserting. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body{
  background:black;
}
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  -ms-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;

}
@keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    100%{transform:rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    100%{transform:rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin{
    0% {transform:rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% {transform:rotateZ(360deg);}
}
```

Check it on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svnn9sna/1/)

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have an explanation for this answer. I had the similar issue a while ago and this is a piece of code that worked for me. I hate IE so I didn't even bother to figure it out.